# Can a timer be scheduled to start at a real time?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Making a simple timer is easy. We know how to build something that fires at a certain interval. Functions and other tasks can be delayed with `Dispatch Queue`. **Has anyone ever tried to start a function with timed precision?**

I've found some documentation that shows that within the Dispatch Framework there are some structs that deal with [microsecond(DispatchWallTime)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchwalltime) and [nanosecond(DispatchTime)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime) precision. Given the assumption that a timer isn't "real-time", **how can we go about firing a function precisely at a later date?**

Here's a simple timer, the goal is to make the start function start at a later time but precisely at the start of a minute or a specific second.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var timeManager = TimeManager()
    @State var date = Date.now.formatted(.dateTime.hour().minute().second())
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current Time: \(date)")
            Text("Elapsed Time: \(timeManager.elapsedTime)").monospacedDigit()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    timeManager.start()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                        .tint(.green)
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    timeManager.stop()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "stop.fill")
                        .tint(.red)
                }
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

class TimeManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var elapsedTime = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    
    // Make this function start at a later date/time with precision.
    func start() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.elapsedTime += 1
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you start the time straight away but add an if statement so that it only updates the elapsedTime variables if current time is equal to or greater than whatever time you want the “timer” to start?

Comment: That would start the timer but it wouldn't start at a time that is 10:00 AM with 0.00 seconds. It would start at 10:00 AM with 0.435etc seconds. I'm looking for precision.

Comment: Your question is unclear! You marked something  like this: "Make this function start at a later date/time with precision." what you mean? you want a timer for a timer?

Comment: Try using `1.0` as value for the parameter `withTimeInterval`, perhaps you'll get a less tolerance, but keep in mind that the system will always reserve a certain amount of tolerance in scheduling timers in order to optimize resources usage.

Comment: Moreover you could also try to refactor leveraging  on the `Publisher` that `Timer` provides via `publish(every:tolerance:on:in:options:)`, knowing you want to have a 0.5 seconds precision for example you could let it emit values with that interval as soon as it is subscribe and let your view update more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time) that gets to the point. It's from Paul Hudson, If anyone would like to answer this question with more depth to it or variations I'll mark it as the answer.

```
let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(5)
let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(runCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

The reason I like this answer is twofold, one you can use a date. Then you can bind this to a date picker or any arbitrary date or time you choose. Two, I like it because it's built right into [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415700-init). Please add your answer if you have a better solution. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can use Calendar method nextDate matching components and pass zero seconds or the next second.